# jQuery adding required to a drop-down box

Tags: jquery

Hi i would like to know how do I add a `required` attribute to a drop-down box? I've searched numerous ways, but none worked; here's my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.orderingmenu .burgers').change(function(){
        var selectVal= $(this).val();
        if(selectVal != 'none'){
            $(this).next().attr('required', true);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I am really out of ideas on how to do this, I tested the selectors and they're working fine, but it just doesn't seem to add in the required attribute to that select field =/ any help please?

What I have tried is:

```
$(this).next().prop('required', true);
$(this).next().attr('required', 'true');
$(this).next().attr('required', '');
$(this).next().prop('required');
```

None have worked =/

**EDIT** the HTML:

```
<div class="orderingmenu" style="margin-bottom: 0.5%;">
        <select name="burgerlist"  class="burgers" style="width: 35%; float: left; font-size: 12px;">
        <option selected="selected" value="none">NONE</option>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        </select>

        <select name="option" id="option" class="setornot" style="width: 30%; font-size: 12px;">
        <option selected="selected" value="none">NONE</option>
        <option value="ALA CARTE">ALA CARTE</option>
        <option value="SET">SET</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" placeholder="ANY REMARKS?" name="remarks" style="width: 30%; float: right; font-size: 12px;">
        </div>
```

I had it looped with a php script, but basically what I wanted to do is so that if there is any selection other than 'none', the other selection is required.

**EDIT 2**

I found out that the problem was that I had the value for none!

Comment: Please show your HTML too

Comment: The first line of "what [you] have tried" should work; how did you verify that it didn't work? Bear in mind the html source won't be updated, just the DOM.

Comment: yea, but having a required attribute in a select field should work just fine right :( ?

Comment: Are you testing in a web browser that supports the required attribute? You haven't mentioned what you're using so you could be using one that doesn't support it.

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer, not as part of the question. In two days you can then accept that answer, and allow the system to denote that it's been 'solved.' Otherwise, only if you don't believe this question could be of use to others, consider deleting the question. Also, [don't put 'solved' in the question title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question), that's not how it works.